# mount error during boot up

Tags: boot, mount

I get the following error during boot up. But this error doesn't get written to boot.log, as it happens in early boot stages.

```
mount: mounts none on /dev/pts failed: Device or resource busy
```

I found this code in /etc/init.d/umountfs file (there is an entry for /dev/pts in it)

```
 PROTECTED_MOUNTS="$(sed -n '0,/^\/[^ ]* \/ /p' /proc/mounts)"
        WEAK_MTPTS="" # be gentle, don't use force
        REG_MTPTS=""
        TMPFS_MTPTS=""
        while read -r DEV MTPT FSTYPE REST
        do
                echo "$PROTECTED_MOUNTS" | grep -qs "^$DEV $MTPT " && continue
                case "$MTPT" in
                  /|/proc|/dev|/.dev|/dev/pts|/dev/shm|/dev/.static/dev|/proc/*$
                        continue
                        ;;
                  /var/run)
                        continue
                        ;;
                  /var/lock)
                        continue
```

The file /etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh also has a similar entry. So if I remove the entry /dev/pts will it solve my issue (the mount error getting displayed at boot up).

Here are the contents of mtab file:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
rpc_pipefs /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw 0 0
/dev/sda6 /media/windisk fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/blandman/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=blandman 0 0
```

Comment: Does the system boot? Is this an upgrade or a clean 10.10 install?

Comment: Yes the system boots. It is an upgrade from 10.04.

Comment: If your system works, I wouldn't edit any of those files (*“if it ain't broke, don't fix it”*).  At least until you know what causes it.

Comment: Can you please post the output of 'cat /etc/mtab' to check mountall...

Comment: This has nothing to do with those umount scripts, so don't edit them. What is your /etc/fstab ? I reckon there's a stray entry in there.

Comment: fstab file doesn't have an entry for /dev/pts.

Comment: Could you append the contents of /etc/fstab to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mountall` program that runs during early boot will mount everything listed in `/lib/init/fstab` and `/etc/fstab`. Check if there are any duplicate entries for `/dev/pts`, and if that doesn't turn anything up, check all the init scripts for mention of it:

```
grep /dev/pts /etc/init/* /etc/init.d/*
```

Comment: lib/init/fstab has an entry for /dev/pts and /etc/fstab doesn't. And there are no duplicate entries for /dev/pts and the grep command above shows the entries in umountfs and umountnfs.sh like the one I posted in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the same message if you try to mount it manually :

```
sudo mount -t devpts -o gid=5,mode=620 devpts /dev/pts
```

Comment: i tried your command: Here is the output                                                             mount: devpts already mounted or /dev/pts busy
mount: according to mtab, none is already mounted on /dev/pts

Comment: The output of your command makee me feel that if we change run level for /dev/pts (makeing it execute little late) in the mtab file it might get solved. How to change run level for mounts?

Answer (score 1):

i feel that the best thing to do is leave the files alone as your system still boots. if it annoys you that much maybe its worth re installing (backing up before of course).
If you are using wubi it might be a good idea looking at the problems listed on their website. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Wubi